# Unable to set property in usercontrol from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvm-light, dependency-properties

I am trying to set a property in a usercontrol from a view model, the control is meant to capture and display the users signature.
I am having problems setting the property in the usercontrol from a view model.
Receiving the signature from the usercontrol into the view model works fine.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be of greatly appreciated.

My test code is below.

**User control XAML:**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="mvvmSignature.ucSignature"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="212" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="#FFEFFCEF">
    <Grid Height="210">
        <InkCanvas MinHeight="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,27,0,0" Name="inkCanvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="278" LostMouseCapture="inkCanvas1_LostMouseCapture" />
        <Button Content="Clear" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,142,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonClear_Click" />
        <Button Content="Load on user control" Height="23" Margin="143,143,36,45" Click="ButtonLoad_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl CodeBehind:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace mvvmSignature
{
    public partial class ucSignature : UserControl
    {
        public ucSignature()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void inkCanvas1_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            SetSignature();
        }
        private void SetSignature()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                inkCanvas1.Strokes.Save(ms);
                foreach (var item in ms.ToArray())
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0},",
                                        item);
                }
                ms.Close();
            }
            var local = sb.ToString().Trim() + "¬¬¬";
            local = local.Replace(",¬¬¬", string.Empty);
            Signature = local;
        }
        private void LoadSignature(string signatureIn)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureIn) || !signatureIn.Contains(",")) return;
            var x = signatureIn.Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
            if (!x.Any()) return;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(x))
            {
                inkCanvas1.Strokes = new StrokeCollection(ms);
                ms.Close();
            }
        }
        public static DependencyProperty SignatureProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Signature", typeof(string),
                                    typeof(ucSignature));
        public string Signature
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(SignatureProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SignatureProperty, value);
                LoadSignature(value);
            }
        }
        private void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Signature = "0,136,3,3,6,72,16,69,53,70,53,17,0,0,128,63,31,9,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,10,237,2,186,1,135,240,12,39,128,97,109,28,4,156,51,90,235,138,135,131,227,95,107,253,119,193,35,104,195,186,246,103,1,195,179,59,78,134,195,179,92,167,188,180,76,206,211,192,77,175,108,211,28,53,136,32,51,41,156,210,3,148,109,22,188,163,105,195,188,11,92,11,184,122,101,188,166,182,124,53,106,153,90,44,217,71,15,64,102,115,59,52,205,105,1,53,128,76,166,179,73,156,202,107,0,195,248,122,106,153,64,22,185,164,210,3,51,154,64,102,51,8,5,174,105,52,128,204,102,19,57,156,215,41,90,69,162,103,1,128,76,128,19,40,4,6,1,102,153,205,96,22,105,156,206,101,53,180,89,230,83,88,4,202,107,0,179,38,120,122,215,52,195,248,120,179,101,25,158,80,195,179,41,156,210,107,50,180,205,38,144,25,156,214,105,52,153,97,249,165,166,101,52,180,205,32,48,0,135,231,164,231,113,153,131,40,225,168,4,6,1,1,128,89,160,22,105,164,214,207,135,32,56,110,3,52,153,192,96,19,80,0,11,68,6,1,105,11,76,2,215,135,50,142,28,77,48,253,160,180,225,232,12,2,107,52,128,205,38,115,91,68,214,105,51,153,77,112,238,30,77,102,80,9,148,214,1,1,154,76,230,64,38,80,8,12,2,101,50,180,205,11,70,29,128,225,236,63,0,153,77,96,19,9,141,154,207,102,153,204,230,19,24,12,209,105,154,64,96,19,89,148,204,0,76,166,118,121,132,204,77,38,179,56,13,170,3,51,128,64,109,24,126,104,154,32,54,121,148,202,103,52,153,77,96,9,144";
        }
        private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            inkCanvas1.Strokes.Clear();
            SetSignature();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML:**

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:mvvmSignature"  x:Class="mvvmSignature.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="490"
    Width="327"        
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">   
<StackPanel>
    <my:ucSignature  Signature ="{Binding Signature,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
    <Button Width ="140" Height ="30" Content ="Load On Main Page" Command="{Binding LoadOnMainPageCommand}" />
    <TextBox FontSize="8"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding Signature,Mode=TwoWay}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="210" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainViewModel:**

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
namespace mvvmSignature.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand LoadOnMainPageCommand { get; set; }
        public const string WelcomeTitlePropertyName = "Signature";
        private string _signature = string.Empty;
        public string Signature 
        {
            get
            {
                return _signature;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_signature == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _signature = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(WelcomeTitlePropertyName);
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoadOnMainPageCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadSignature);
        }

        private void LoadSignature()
        {
            Signature ="0,136,3,3,6,72,16,69,53,70,53,17,0,0,128,63,31,9,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,10,237,2,186,1,135,240,12,39,128,97,109,28,4,156,51,90,235,138,135,131,227,95,107,253,119,193,35,104,195,186,246,103,1,195,179,59,78,134,195,179,92,167,188,180,76,206,211,192,77,175,108,211,28,53,136,32,51,41,156,210,3,148,109,22,188,163,105,195,188,11,92,11,184,122,101,188,166,182,124,53,106,153,90,44,217,71,15,64,102,115,59,52,205,105,1,53,128,76,166,179,73,156,202,107,0,195,248,122,106,153,64,22,185,164,210,3,51,154,64,102,51,8,5,174,105,52,128,204,102,19,57,156,215,41,90,69,162,103,1,128,76,128,19,40,4,6,1,102,153,205,96,22,105,156,206,101,53,180,89,230,83,88,4,202,107,0,179,38,120,122,215,52,195,248,120,179,101,25,158,80,195,179,41,156,210,107,50,180,205,38,144,25,156,214,105,52,153,97,249,165,166,101,52,180,205,32,48,0,135,231,164,231,113,153,131,40,225,168,4,6,1,1,128,89,160,22,105,164,214,207,135,32,56,110,3,52,153,192,96,19,80,0,11,68,6,1,105,11,76,2,215,135,50,142,28,77,48,253,160,180,225,232,12,2,107,52,128,205,38,115,91,68,214,105,51,153,77,112,238,30,77,102,80,9,148,214,1,1,154,76,230,64,38,80,8,12,2,101,50,180,205,11,70,29,128,225,236,63,0,153,77,96,19,9,141,154,207,102,153,204,230,19,24,12,209,105,154,64,96,19,89,148,204,0,76,166,118,121,132,204,77,38,179,56,13,170,3,51,128,64,109,24,126,104,154,32,54,121,148,202,103,52,153,77,96,9,144";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which property are you trying set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote portions of your ucSignature class to properly declare and use the Signature property in your code behind. Use this class definition instead, and let me know if it works any better.

```
public partial class ucSignature : UserControl
{
    public ucSignature()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void inkCanvas1_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            inkCanvas1.Strokes.Save(ms);
            foreach (var item in ms.ToArray())
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0},", item);
            }
            ms.Close();
        }
        var local = sb.ToString().Trim() + "¬¬¬";
        local = local.Replace(",¬¬¬", string.Empty);

        this.SetValue(SignatureProperty, local);
    }

    private void LoadSignature(string signatureIn)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureIn) || !signatureIn.Contains(",")) return;
        var x = signatureIn.Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
        if (!x.Any()) return;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(x))
        {
            inkCanvas1.Strokes = new StrokeCollection(ms);
            ms.Close();
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty SignatureProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Signature",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ucSignature),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(OnSignaturePropertyChanged));

    public static string GetSignature(ucSignature signature)
    {
        return (string)signature.GetValue(SignatureProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSignature(ucSignature signature, string value)
    {
        signature.SetValue(SignatureProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSignaturePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var signature = obj as ucSignature;

        if (signature != null)
        {
            LoadSignature(args.NewValue.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetValue(SignatureProperty, "0,136,3,3,6,72,16,69,53,70,53,17,0,0,128,63,31,9,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,10,237,2,186,1,135,240,12,39,128,97,109,28,4,156,51,90,235,138,135,131,227,95,107,253,119,193,35,104,195,186,246,103,1,195,179,59,78,134,195,179,92,167,188,180,76,206,211,192,77,175,108,211,28,53,136,32,51,41,156,210,3,148,109,22,188,163,105,195,188,11,92,11,184,122,101,188,166,182,124,53,106,153,90,44,217,71,15,64,102,115,59,52,205,105,1,53,128,76,166,179,73,156,202,107,0,195,248,122,106,153,64,22,185,164,210,3,51,154,64,102,51,8,5,174,105,52,128,204,102,19,57,156,215,41,90,69,162,103,1,128,76,128,19,40,4,6,1,102,153,205,96,22,105,156,206,101,53,180,89,230,83,88,4,202,107,0,179,38,120,122,215,52,195,248,120,179,101,25,158,80,195,179,41,156,210,107,50,180,205,38,144,25,156,214,105,52,153,97,249,165,166,101,52,180,205,32,48,0,135,231,164,231,113,153,131,40,225,168,4,6,1,1,128,89,160,22,105,164,214,207,135,32,56,110,3,52,153,192,96,19,80,0,11,68,6,1,105,11,76,2,215,135,50,142,28,77,48,253,160,180,225,232,12,2,107,52,128,205,38,115,91,68,214,105,51,153,77,112,238,30,77,102,80,9,148,214,1,1,154,76,230,64,38,80,8,12,2,101,50,180,205,11,70,29,128,225,236,63,0,153,77,96,19,9,141,154,207,102,153,204,230,19,24,12,209,105,154,64,96,19,89,148,204,0,76,166,118,121,132,204,77,38,179,56,13,170,3,51,128,64,109,24,126,104,154,32,54,121,148,202,103,52,153,77,96,9,144");
    }
    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.Clear();
        this.SetValue(SignatureProperty, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works a treat.
I had to modify the following OnSignaturePropertyChanged to cater for the non static InkCanvas control.

'private static void OnSignaturePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
 var signature = obj as ucSignature;
 if (signature != null) signature.LoadSignature(args.NewValue.ToString());
}
'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your MainViewModel as the `DataContext` of your MainWindow so the binding works.  Unless you're setting it in the constructor, I don't see it being set anywhere. You can try something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>         
<local:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />     
</Application.Resources>

DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"
```

Comment: He actually did set the data context.
`DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">`

Comment: @bugged87  Okay, where are "Main and "Locator" in the Binding?  Are these specific to MVVM-Light?

Comment: Yes, the MVVM-Light toolkit adds a ViewModelLocator class to your new WPF project. This class contains static properties for each view model, as well as non-static properties for binding purposes. Therefore, by default the MainViewModel would have a static property declared for it called "MainStatic" and a non-static property called "Main" in the ViewModelLocator.
The locator would be referenced in your XAML by adding the following to your application resources:

`<vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourApp.ViewModels"
                             x:Key="Locator" />`

Comment: @bugged87  Thanks for the clarification, it's clearer now.  I didn't notice the MVVM-Light tag initially, so my fault.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that it's the Signature property that you are trying to set, mainly because that's what your user control is all about AND that's where I see an issue.

After you set the Signature property, you call `RaisePropertyChanged` on a different property: the WelcomeTitlePropertyName property. You should be calling `RaisePropertyChanged` on the same property you set or else your UI (i.e. your user control) won't know about it.

For example, in your MainWindow XAML you placed a ucSignature element like this:

```
<my:ucSignature Signature ="{Binding Signature,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

That part is fine, but in your ViewModel that property should be defined like this:

```
private string _signature = string.Empty;
public string Signature 
    {
        get { return _signature; }
        set
        {
            if (_signature == value)
                return;

            _signature = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(Signature);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it's okay here because that property is a Static and has a value of "Signature", the same as the property name.  Kind of an odd way of doing it, however.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I wasn't paying attention because I use a separate method to call RaisePropertyChanged that take's the actual property as an expression like this:
`NotifySetProperty(ref _signature, value, () => Signature);`
And that's all that goes in my setter. The NotifySetProperty method takes care of checking for null and equality as well as raising the PropertyChanged event.